# Воспроизведение аудиофайла в формате OggOpus в JAVA

Tags: java, ogg, yandex-speechkit

Работаю с API Yandex SpeechKit. При запросе данных через API возвращается бинарное содержимое аудиофайла. Это "содержимое" я пытался сохранить в формат **.ogg** и затем воспроизвести в Java. Пробовал обычные методы Java и множество библиотек все безуспешно. Затем попытался сохранять файл в формате **.opus** и конвертировать его.

Для конвертации использовал библиотеки **Jorbis, EasyOgg, Vorbisspi, LibJitsi, Jogg.**
Для воспроизведения использовал библиотеки **TinySound**, а также "самописные" варианты.
Как итог, ничего не работает.

Для представления с чем работаю вот [ссылка](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/speechkit/tts/request) на документацию Yandex.

Фрагмент кода с сохранением файла.

```
private void getSynthesizeVoiceInFile(String filePath, HttpURLConnection http){
    File file = null;
    try {
        int count = 1, c;
        file = new File(filePath + ".opus");
        while (file.exists()){
            file = new File(filePath + "_" + count + ".opus");
            count++;
        }

        InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1) fos.write(c);

        fos.close();
        is.close();
        log.DEBUG("GetSynthesizeVoice.getSynthesizeVoiceInFile: Create file. Filepath: " + file.getPath());
    }catch (IOException | NullPointerException e){
        log.ERROR("GetSynthesizeVoice.getSynthesizeVoiceInFile: Failed to write or create file. Filepath: " + file.getPath());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Надеюсь знающие люди подскажут.
Я уже просто не знаю в какую сторону копать...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251017/how-do-i-play-opus-encoded-audio-in-java покажите как пробовали. Конвертации в вашем коде не происходит на данный момент, просто запись потока байт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы, думаю некоторым будет это полезно. А решение простое. На этапе формирования http запроса дополнительным параметром передал строку с кодировкой
`&format=lpcm&sampleRateHertz=48000`

После этого изменил сохранение файла в формат **.raw**

Соответственно функция сохранения приобрела следующий вид:

```
private void getSynthesizeVoiceInFile(String filePath, HttpURLConnection http){
        File file = null;
        AudioInputStream din = null;
        try {
            int count = 1, c;
            file = new File(filePath + ".raw");
            while (file.exists()){
                file = new File(filePath + "_" + count + ".raw");
                count++;
            }

            InputStream is = http.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            while ((c = is.read()) != -1) fos.write(c);

            fos.close();
            new testPlay().play(new FileInputStream(file));
            is.close();
            log.DEBUG("GetSynthesizeVoice.getSynthesizeVoiceInFile: Create file. Filepath: " + file.getPath());
        }catch (IOException | NullPointerException e){
            log.ERROR("GetSynthesizeVoice.getSynthesizeVoiceInFile: Failed to write or create file. Filepath: " + file.getPath());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Поскольку на выходе получается аудиофайл с кодировкой LPCM, то его получается "проиграть" без особых танцев с бубном и дополнительных библиотек.

Класс который вызывается в коде `new testPlay().play(new FileInputStream(file));`, полностью представлен ниже:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class testPlay {
    public void play(InputStream rawfile)  {
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            BufferedInputStream raw = new BufferedInputStream(rawfile);

            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(
                    48000,
                    16,
                    1,
                    true,
                    false
            );
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format, 1024);
            line.start();
            while ((len = raw.read(buf)) != -1)
                line.write(buf, 0, len);
            line.drain();
            line.stop();
            line.close();
        }catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```